# Calculating cost of edit operations in List haskell

Tags: haskell

```
data Edit = 
        Change Char Char|
        Copy Char|
        Delete Char|
        Insert Char
        deriving (Eq, Show)

cost :: [Edit] -> Int
cost edits
    = length ( filter (\x -> x /= Copy) edits )

main :: IO()
main
    = putStrLn ( show ( cost [Copy 'e', Copy 'x', Insert 'm', Insert 'o', Change 'e' 'u', Copy 't', Delete 'e', Change 'r' 'h'] ) )
```

I am trying to calculate the cost of List using an algebraic data type, each edit costs 1 apart from copy which costs 0.

I am currently getting the error:

```
    * Couldn't match type `Edit' with `Char -> Edit'
      Expected type: [Char -> Edit]
        Actual type: [Edit]
    * In the second argument of `filter', namely `edits'
      In the first argument of `length', namely
        `(filter (\ x -> x /= Copy) edits)'
      In the expression: length (filter (\ x -> x /= Copy) edits)
                                        ^^^^^
```

I cant seen to grasp algebraic types so any help appreciated

Comment: Have you studied the error message carefully? What do you think it's telling you, or what specifically are you struggling with? (reading type errors is a really important skill to learn/practice so I think you'd be better served with a hint rather than someone just telling you how to fix your code)

Comment: Fair point, i managed to get through the second error but the first one has really stumped me

Comment: Hint: what is the type of `Copy`? What is the type of `Copy 'a'`? (You can ask `ghci` by doing `Prelude> :t Copy 'a'`) What is the type of the `x` bound in the lambda in `filter`?

Comment: the type of Copy 'a' is Edit, so im guessing the x in the lambda function isnt. Can i please get a hint on how to make it so, as i thought the x would be polymorphic :/

Comment: You know the type of `Copy 'a'` is `Edit`, so it stands to reason that `Copy` on its own is `Char -> Edit` (a function that takes a `Char` and returns an `Edit`). On the other hand, `x` is an `Edit`, which is a different type.

Comment: Hopefully the last comment ^ helps clear up the type error. What you really want to do is not use `(/=) :: Eq a=> a -> a -> Bool`, but instead do `filter isCopy ...` where `isCopy` is defined using pattern-matching

Comment: If you want some motivation on how to write an `isCopy` function then look at the `Data.Maybe.isJust` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Copy` is a constructor of `Edit` with one field of type `Char`, so it has the following function type:

```
Copy :: Char -> Edit
```

In fact, with `{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax #-}` you can write the type of each constructor explicitly in the definition, which you may find clearer:

```
data Edit where
  Change :: Char -> Char -> Edit
  Copy   :: Char -> Edit
  Delete :: Char -> Edit
  Insert :: Char -> Edit
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Therefore the function that you pass to `filter`, `\x -> x /= Copy`, has the following inferred type, because you’re trying to compare `x` to the function `Copy`:

```
(Eq (Char -> Edit))
  => (Char -> Edit) -> Bool
```

`filter` has this type:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

And because `a` is deduced as equal to `Char -> Edit`, the type of `filter (\x -> x /= Copy)` is inferred as:

```
(Eq (Char -> Edit))
  => [Char -> Edit] -> [Char -> Edit]
```

Which of course is not what you want, for two reasons—first, it doesn’t express what you want (that an edit wasn’t constructed with the `Copy` constructor), and second, it can’t work because there’s no instance `Eq (Char -> Edit)` that lets you compare functions, nor could you write one since functions aren’t comparable.

If you want to check whether a value of type `Edit` was constructed with `Copy` in the call to `filter`, you should use *pattern-matching* instead. A simple way to do that is to write a function:

```
isCopy :: Edit -> Bool
isCopy edit = case edit of
  {- your implementation here -}
```

Then use that in the condition of `filter`:

```
filter (\x -> {- your condition here -})
```

And it will have type `[Edit] -> [Edit]` as desired. Instead of writing a separate function `isCopy`, you can also write this inline using a `case` expression:

```
filter (\x -> case x of
  {- your implementation here -})
```

Another way to solve this problem is to break it down into smaller parts, by writing a function `cost1 :: Edit -> Int` which returns the cost of a *single* edit:

```
cost1 :: Edit -> Int
cost1 edit = case edit of
  Change _ _ -> 1
  Copy _ -> 0
  {- remaining cases -}
```

Then `cost` can use `map` or a list comprehension to apply `cost1` to the whole list of edits, and take the `sum` of the result.